# C++ Performance: pass by reference for object vs for function

Tags: c++, performance, reference

Here is a piece of code in my daily work.

Here is class Price:

```
// In class Price.hpp
private:
bool value = false;
// others
std::vector<int> vec;
...

public:
getBoolValue() { return value; }
setBoolValue( bool iValue ) { value = iValue };

// a lot of setters & getters for the others
...
```

Here is Compute.hpp

```
// In class Compute.hpp
// First proposition
void computeAmount ( const Price & iPrice )

// Second proposition
void computeAmount ( const bool iValue )
```

Here is Compute.cpp

```
// First proposition
void Compute::computeAmount ( const Price & iPrice ) {
    if ( iPrice.getBoolValue() ) {
      // do something
    }
}

// Second proposition
void Compute::computeAmount ( const bool iValue ) {
    if ( iValue  ) {
      // do something
    }
}
```

In main.cpp, if we call this two different functions by this way:

```
Compute aCompute;
Price aPrice;
// Do a lot of set for those two
....

// Discussion
aCompute.computeAmount ( aPrice );

aCompute.computeAmount ( aPrice.getBoolValue() );
```

Price is a very big object. So if we talk about the performance (pass by reference of a big object vs pass by a returned value of its member function ) Which one is more efficient in your opinion? I would say that's the same and there is no difference in terms of performance.

Comment: Measure please!

Comment: "_Which one is more efficient in your opinion?_" Why should _opinions_ matter in this case? Profile it, and see, for your own, which is more efficient.

Comment: Write your own profiler and measure it. It's easy to write a simple profiler

Comment: This is unlikely to be the cause of any of your performance issues as neither is going to be particularly slow; so the phrase "premature optimisation" jumps to mind.   The company would gain more from you profiling to establish which functions / algorithms in the whole program need improving, rather than trying to work out if this one specifically could be improved.

Comment: I would assume that `// do something` is the expensive piece, and that you are focusing on the wrong part of the code.

Comment: There is no point in worrying about the relative cost of these until you have made sure that the rest of your program is truly optimal and no further improvements can be made.

Comment: I would assume that the two would be **identically performant**, because they are semantically identical. The compiler will probably generate **the same output** for both.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, if you pass the object `aPrice` itself, it will be be passed as an address into the memory.
So inside Compute.cpp , when you use `iPrice`, it basically calls `aPrice` and its functions, thus, giving the same functionality with a reference.

Thus, negligible difference would be there in the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bit of an XY problem, in that it seems more a question of class design

If the calculation only makes sense for a `Price`, the calculation should be part of the `Price` class i.e.

```
Price::computeAmount();  // reference ivalue directly
```

Or it is of general worth in which case, putting it in a `Compute` class makes sense:

```
Compute::computeAmount(bool ivalue);  // use ivalue as a param
```

It does not seem to make sense for a `Price` to be passed to another class to pull out just its one member

Performance seems not to be the issue as most compilers will equivalate the two (or three if you include the member function above)